# How to test address(0) with Hard Hat?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

This is my test, which fails and it should pass

```
  it('Should not allow 0 address to be added', async () => {
    await expect(greeter.addWhitelistAddress('0x0')).to.be.revertedWith(
      'Invalid address'
    );
  });
```

and this is my function

```
   function addWhitelistAddress(address _wlAddress)
        public
    {
        require(_wlAddress != address(0), 'Invalid address');
        whitelisted[_wlAddress] = true;
    }
```

Comment: Hardhat offers its own [Chai matchers](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview). Take a look at my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template), which bundles those matchers, among other things.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ethers constants](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/constants/).

In hardhat tests, ethers lib are imported by default, so you don't need to add the require sentence.

Happy coding!

```
     it('Should not allow 0 address to be added', async () => {
        await expect(greeter.addWhitelistAddress(ethers.constants.AddressZero)).to.be.revertedWith(
          'Invalid address'
        );
      });
```

Comment: I prefer to define my own constant for that: `export const ZERO_ADDRESS = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000';`. It's much more accessible compared to `ethers.constants.AddressZero`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openzeppelin's test library for this.

```
it("Should return an error when address 0 is entered", async function () {
    const {
        constants,
        expectRevert,
    } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
  
    const AWLContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("AddWhiteList");
    const addWhiteList = await AWLContract.deploy();

    console.log(constants.ZERO_ADDRESS);
    await addWhiteList.deployed();
   
    await expectRevert(
        addWhiteList.addWhitelistAddress(constants.ZERO_ADDRESS),
        'Invalid address',
    );

});
```

So you should change the quotes in the messages with "Invalid address".